# avoiding iframes, but having some iframe like activity in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, iframe, html, partial

I have two sites, my main site and a help site with documentation.  The main site is rails but the other is simple a wordpress like blog.  Currently I have it being pulled into the main site with an iframe, but is there a good way to pull in the html from the other site as some sort of cross-domain (sub-domain actually) partial?  Or should I just stick with what works?

Comment: While you might be able to go about it a different way, what's wrong with your iFrame solution?

Answer (score 1):

If the data sources were all on the same domain, you would be able to utilize straight [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) to fetch your supplemental content and graft it onto your page.  But, since the data is from different domains, the [same origin security policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) built into web browsers will prevent that from working.

A popular work around is called [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which will let you fetch the data from any cooperating server.  Your implementation might look something like this (using jQuery):

```
$.getJSON(
  "http://my.website.com/pageX?callback=?",
  function(data) { 
    $("#help").append(data) 
  } 
)
```

The only hitch is that the data returned by your server must be wrapped as a javascript function call.  For example, if your data was:

```
<h1>Topic Foo</h1>
```

Then your server must respond to the JSONP request like this:

```
callbackFunction("<h1>Topic Foo</h1>")
```